# More elegant solution for python imports across app/tests?

Tags: python, unit-testing

I'm trying to keep my code reasonably organized by putting tests in a separate directory from my app. However, imports work *either* for the app *or* for the tests, but not both. Here's a contrived example that illustrates my current problem:

```
myapp/
  app/
    main.py
    settings.py
    moods.py
  test/
    test_moods.py
```

Contents of files as follows:

**main.py**

```
import settings
from moods import Moods

words = Moods(settings.EXAMPLE)
print(words.excited())
```

**settings.py**

```
EXAMPLE = "Wow$ Python$"
DELIM = "$"
```

**moods.py**

```
import settings

class Moods:
    def __init__(self, text):
        self.text = text

    def excited(self):
        return self.text.replace(settings.DELIM, "!!!")
```

**test_moods.py**

```
import sys, os, unittest
sys.path.insert(0, os.path.abspath('..'))

from app.moods import Moods

class TestMood(unittest.TestCase):
    def setUp(self):
        self.words = Moods("Broken imports$ So sad$")

    def test_mood(self):
        self.assertEqual(self.words.excited(), "Broken imports!!! So sad!!!")
        with self.assertRaises(AttributeError):
            self.words.angry()

if __name__ == "__main__":
    unittest.main()
```

In the current state, from `myapp/` I can run the following successfully:

```
>> python3 app/main.py
Wow!!! Python!!!
```

But when I try to run tests, the import fails in moods.py:

```
>> python3 -m unittest discover test/
ImportError: Failed to import test module: test_moods
[ stack trace here pointing to first line of moods.py ]
ImportError: No module named 'settings'
```

If I modify line 1 of moods.py to read `from app import settings`, the test will pass, but normal execution of the app fails because it sees no module `app`.

The only solutions I can think of are

1. Putting the tests in the same directory as the code (which I was trying to avoid)
2. Adding the `sys.path.insert(0, os.path.abspath('..'))` to each file in my app to make the imports work the same as the test ones do (which seems messy)

Is there are more elegant way to solve this import problem?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should have both `app` and `test` directory in `PYTHONPATH`.

One way is to replace this:

```
sys.path.insert(0, os.path.abspath('..'))

from app.moods import Moods
```

with this:

```
sys.path.insert(0, os.path.abspath('../app'))

from moods import Moods
```

Or you can set the `PYTHONPATH` environament variable before running the tests.

Why? Because when you run `main.py`, then `app` is in the path, not `app/..`, so you want to have the same when running tests.

Comment: Hmm... so far, this solution seems to be the most promising. It's clean, and keeps the path modification to the test files. However, it doesn't work. Implementing the code change as proposed above yields: `ImportError: No module named 'moods'`

Comment: Ok... oddly, setting `os.path.abspath('app')` worked. I suppose this is because I'm running tests from the parent directory and it's aware of the app directory?

Comment: @vastlysuperiorman If you are running from the parent directory, then `app` is the correct path, yes.